# what's the best practice to merge rdds in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have got multi RDDs as result and want to merge them, they are of the same format:

```
RDD(id, HashMap[String, HashMap[String, Int]])
    ^             ^        ^
    |             |        |
  identity     category   distribution of the category
```

Here is a example of that rdd:

```
(1001, {age={10=3,15=5,16=8, ...}})
```

The first key`String` of the `HashMap[String, HashMap]` is the category of the statistic and the `HashMap[String, Int]` in the `HashMap[String, HashMap]` is the distribution of the category. After calculate each distribution of vary categories, I want to merge them by the identity so that I can store the results to database. Here is what I got currently:

```
def mergeRDD(rdd1: RDD[(String, util.HashMap[String, Object])],
              rdd2:RDD[(String, util.HashMap[String, Object])]): RDD[(String, util.HashMap[String, Object])] = {

  val mergedRDD = rdd1.join(rdd2).map{
    case (id, (m1, m2)) => {
      m1.putAll(m2)
      (id, m1)
    }
  }
  mergedRDD
}
val mergedRDD = mergeRDD(provinceRDD, mergeRDD(mergeRDD(levelRDD, genderRDD), actionTypeRDD))
```

I write a function `mergeRDD` so that I can merge two rdds each time, But I found that function is not very elegant, as a newbie to scala, any inspiring is appreciated.

Comment: what are the properties of your merge function ?

Comment: @eliasah thank you for reply, but what do you mean by properties?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any easy way to achieve this, without hitting performance.
Reason being, you are not simply merging two rdd, rather, you want your hashmap to have consolidated values after union of rdd.

Now, your merge function is wrong. In current state join will actually do inner join, missing out rows present in either rdd not present in other one.

Correct way would be something like.

```
val mergedRDD = rdd1.union(rdd2).reduceByKey{
    case (m1, m2) => {
      m1.putAll(m2)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the `java.util.HashMap` with `scala.collection.immutable.Map`

From there:

```
val rdds      = List(provinceRDD, levelRDD, genderRDD, actionTypeRDD)
val unionRDD  = rdds.reduce(_ ++ _)
val mergedRDD = unionRDD.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

This is assuming that categories don't overlap between rdds.